# Is there a way to records in bundles in a database?

Tags: pdo, fetch

I have a large mysql database (several 100000 records). I use PDO to access it. I need to fetch data, in units of approximately 100 records.
PDO:: fetchall  results in too many records and exhausts the PC memory.
PDO::fetch gets me one record only.

Is there a way to request the next n (say 100) records?

Thanks

Comment: use a `LIMIT` clause in the query itself.

Answer (score 0):

> PDO::fetch gets me one record only.

You can always make *another* call to fetch to get another record. And so on, until all the records get fetched, just like it shown in every example:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch() {
  print $row[0];
}
```

Note that you may also set [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#mysqlnd) to false in order to reduce the memory consumption

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL client-server protocol would allow to fetch a certain number (>1) of rows from the resultset of a statement in a single response packet (if the data fits the 2<sup>24</sup>-1 bytes limit). The [COM_STMT_FETCH command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/com-stmt-fetch.html#packet-COM_STMT_FETCH) has the field `num rows` which in the OP's case *could* be set to 100.
But the mysqlnd implementation currently [sets this field explicitly and exclusivly to 1](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_ps.c#L1062).
So, yes, currently your only option seems to be an unbuffered query and living with the (small) network overhead of fetching the records one by one, e.g.

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly', array(
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY=>false,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));
setup($pdo);

// use an unbuffered query
// so the complete result set isn't transfered into the php instance's memory 
// before ->execute() returns
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id FROM soFoo WHERE id>?');
$stmt->execute( array(5) );

$rowsPerChunk = 10;
do {
    // not saying that you have to use LimitIterator, it's just one example of how you can process the chunks
    // and a demonstration that PDOStatement implements Traversable
    // all in all the example doesn't do very useful things ;-)
    $lit = new LimitIterator(new IteratorIterator($stmt), 0, $rowsPerChunk);
    doSomething($lit);
}
while( $lit->getPosition()===$rowsPerChunk);

function doSomething(Iterator $it) {
    foreach($it as $row) {
        printf('%2d ', $row['id']); // yeah, yeah, not that useful....
    }
    echo "\r\n-------\r\n";
}



function setup($pdo) {
    $pdo->exec('
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE soFoo (
            id int auto_increment, 
            primary key(id)
        )
    ');
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO soFoo VALUES ()');
    for($i=0; $i<44; $i++) {
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```